# AngularJS Promise adds resolved value to $$v instead of turning into the object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I noticed that if I do the following:

```
var myItem = getObject();
console.log( myItem );

function getObject()
{
  var def = $q.defer();
  $http.get('my_url').success(function(result)
   {
      def.resolve( result); 
   } );

  return def.promise;
}
```

When this happens, the ajax request is made as expected, however in the `console.log` line, it actually logs a promise which has a `$$v` value to which all of the json data returned by  the ajax request is attached.

So it doesn't actually transform the promise object into the returned json data, but instead it just adds it as a `$$v` variable.

Is there any way to change this behavior and to have the object be transformed completely into the result?

Answer (score 1):

$http.get already returns a promise so you can just do :

```
function getObject()
{
   return $http.get('my_url')
}
```

In the following code, console.log won't wait for the promise to resolve, it just prints out a prommise object:

```
var myItem = getObject();
console.log( myItem );
```

Instead you need to pass a callback function:

```
getObject().success(function(data){
  $scope.myVar = data;
}
```

Comment: That wasn't my question, my question is, is there a way that after the ajax request finishes, the promise is completely changed into the return value from the request? e.g `item = $http.get(); alert(item.value);`

Comment: Looking at your code in the question, I think this is the right answer. The promise is not resolved when `console.log` is called and $$v should be empty. However once you expand the object in console, it _might_ have been loaded already and the $$v value is populated. In any case, you console.log should happen after resolve, not before it, to actually access the response.

Comment: @ClickUpvote check the updated answer, you can assign the data to a variable once the promise is resolved,